# automatically update index haystack directly with the database without using django models

Tags: database, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Hello forgive my ignorance, because I have little time scheduling and my bad English .
My question is about how to make haystack update its index making changes to the database outside of the models, I mean , imagine delete a registry by hand from my database, or using third-party programs that add and delete records in the database . How I can make these records automatically update haystack , it is possible to do this ? ( And not have to use the --remove command update_index because my database is very large) Well, I think RealTimeProcessor only does using django models. Thank you in advance to everyone for this great community.

Answer (score 0):

If you change DB without any notification to django, it has no way to react. You may try to write a trigger that would log your activities, of changing data, into a table. Then you could write crontab task to update indicies related with that particular data.